# How to block those requests?

Tags: windows-firewall, iis-8.5, request-filtering

One of my website seems to be being under attack.
I am getting requests, as shown below, from several IPs addresses.
Is there a way to block them?

[image: From event viewer]

Comment: If the queries make no sense, use URL Rewrite rules to abort the connections. You should also consider a firewall service that filters out such attacks automatically.

Comment: This is normal in Case, your Server can be reached by 1) The Internet 2) via http/s - however take a look into https://www.calcomsoftware.com/use-iis-request-filtering-rules-to-block-sql-injection-attacks/